# UseReducer is called twice when dispatching data from useEffect hook within child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-reducer

I am making a todo/shopping list in ReactJS. Besides being able to add items manually to the list by input, the user should also be able to add items programmatically.

I am using `createContext()` and `useReducer` for managing the `state()`.

When I add items programmatically by providing an array through the props and listen for changes in `useEffect`, the `useEffect` and `dispatch` fires twice despite that I only changed the props once.

However this is NOT happening when I provide the array of items through props the first time.

Consequently, after the first time, when `dispatch` fires twice the list get duplicates (also duplicate keys).

Is it happening due to some re-rendering process that I am not aware of? Any help is much appreciated as I am really stuck on this one.

Here is the code:

Context provider component containing the useEffect that triggers the dispatch method from useReducer when the props change:

```js
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import todosReducer from '../reducers/todos.reducer';
import { ADD_INGREDIENT_ARRAY } from '../constants/actions';

const defaultItems = [
  { id: '0', task: 'Item1', completed: false },
  { id: '1', task: 'Item2', completed: false },
  { id: '2', task: 'Item3', completed: false }
];

export const TodosContext = createContext();
export const DispatchContext = createContext();

export function TodosProvider(props) {
  const [todos, dispatch] = useReducer(todosReducer, defaultItems)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.ingredientArray.length) {
      dispatch({ type: ADD_INGREDIENT_ARRAY, task: props.ingredientArray });
    }
  }, [props.ingredientArray])

  return (
    <TodosContext.Provider value={todos}>
      <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {props.children}
      </DispatchContext.Provider>
    </TodosContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

My reducer function (`ADD_INGREDIENT_ARRAY` is the one that gets called from above code snippet) :

```
import uuidv4 from "uuid/dist/v4";
import { useReducer } from "react";
import {
  ADD_TODO,
  REMOVE_TODO,
  TOGGLE_TODO,
  EDIT_TODO,
  ADD_INGREDIENT_ARRAY
} from '../constants/actions';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return [{ id: uuidv4(), task: action.task, completed: false }, ...state];
    case REMOVE_TODO:
      return state.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.id);
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      return state.map(todo =>
        todo.id === action.id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
      );
    case EDIT_TODO:
      return state.map(todo =>
        todo.id === action.id ? { ...todo, task: action.task } : todo
      );
    case ADD_INGREDIENT_ARRAY: 
        console.log('THE REDUCER WAS CALLED')
        return [...action.task.map(ingr => ({ id: uuidv4(), task: ingr.name, completed: false }) ), ...state]
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

The list component that renders each item and uses the context from above code snippet:

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { TodosContext, DispatchContext } from '../contexts/todos.context';
import Todo from './Todo';

function TodoList() {
  const todos = useContext(TodosContext);

  return (
    <ul style={{ paddingLeft: 10, width: "95%" }}>
      {todos.map(todo => (
        <Todo key={Math.random()} {...todo} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default TodoList;
```

And the app component containing the list which is wrapped in the context provider that passes the props:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import { TodosProvider } from '../contexts/todos.context';
import TodoForm from './TodoForm';
import TodoList from './TodoList';

function TodoApp({ ingredientArray }) {
  return (
    <TodosProvider ingredientArray={ingredientArray}>
      <TodoForm/>
      <TodoList/>
    </TodosProvider>
  );
}

export default TodoApp;
```

And the top level component that passes the props as well:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import TodoApp from './TodoApp';
import useStyles from '../styles/AppStyles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

function App({ ingredientArray }) {
  const classes = useStyles();  

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={3}>
      <div className={classes.App}>
        <header className={classes.header}>
          <h1>
            Shoppinglist
        </h1>
        </header>
        <TodoApp ingredientArray={ingredientArray} />
      </div>
    </Paper>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The parent component where ingredientArray is made. It takes the last recipe in the state.recipes array and passes it as props to the shoppingList:

```
...
  const handleSetNewRecipe = (recipe) => {
    recipe.date = state.date;
    setState({ ...state, recipes: [...state.recipes, recipe] })
  }
...

 {recipesOpen ? <RecipeDialog
    visible={recipesOpen}
    setVisible={setRecipesOpen}
    chosenRecipe={handleSetNewRecipe}
  /> : null}

...

 <Grid item className={classes.textAreaGrid}>
     <ShoppingList ingredientArray={state.recipes.length ? state.recipes.reverse()[0].ingredients : []}/>
 </Grid>

....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show where `ingredientArray` is being declared originally?

Comment: Yes, it is originally derived from the state of the parent component:

<ShoppingList ingredientArray={state.recipes.length ? state.recipes.reverse( [0].ingredients : []}/>

Comment: Should have updated the question now with a snippet from the parent component

Comment: The Array method `reverse` is mutating - React state relies on immutability so calling this method on it directly is likely to cause peculiarities, although I can't see exactly where the issue would be. Could you try this instead just to make sure: `state.recipies[state.recipies.length-1].ingredients`.

Comment: You are right! This worked for me, thank you very much. If you post this as an answer I will accept it ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad we got this sorted. As per the comments on the main post, mutating React state directly instead of updating it via a setter function can cause the actual value of the state to become out of sync with dependent components and effects further down the tree.

I still can't completely reason why it would be causing your specific issue in this case, but regardless, removing the mutative call to `reverse` and replacing it with this simple index calculation appears to have solved the issue:

`state.recipies[state.recipies.length-1].ingredients`